# WebdriverIO Page Objects Inheritance

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I'm building an e2e testing suite using WebdriverIO and I'm stuck at creating inheritance between page objects.

In Protractor we can pass through parameter the context and then, just search the element inside that context. For instance,

`var pageObject = context.element(by.css('.some-class'));`

For instance,

here is Header on HomePage

```
var HomePage = require('./home.page');
module.exports = Object.create(HomePage, {
    headerModule: {get: function () {return browser.element('.header');}
});
```

An here is Footer also on HomePage

```
var HomePage = require('./home.page');
module.exports = Object.create(HomePage, {
    footerModule: {get: function () {return browser.element('.footer');}
});
```

In both modules, I have the same button and I want to create just one page object for the button used in both cases. Which page should I use to inherit? I don't know how to pass by parameter, the parent page object.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to pass context between page objects. Your main script will instantiate and consume the different page objects. The context should be contained within the page objects themselves. Can you give a more detailed example of when you would pass context between page objects?

Comment: Can you please have a look again? I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have enough info to understand what you are trying to do but I think you might be confused about how page objects work. From the example that you gave, you want to fetch the header and footer for the home page. In the page object model you would create a home page class (the page object) and within that class you would declare two methods, one to fetch the header and one to fetch the footer. Both methods are part of the same page object.

In your script, you would instantiate the home page class (page object) and then call the methods to fetch the footer and/or header. At this point, there's no need to pass context. All the code to fetch the header/footer is contained inside the method inside the home page class.

I don't know protractor so I can't write you some sample code but I did find this page that looks like a pretty good intro to page objects using protractor. I would suggest that you read it and probably search for some more guides using 'protractor selenium page object' as search terms or something similar. There are several results there that look like they might be good. Even if you can't find a lot of articles for page objects in protractor, reading articles for other languages will help you better understand the concepts so hopefully you can implement them yourself in the language of your choosing.

https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings